# Hidding files in sdcard

Tags: android, file

I have created a .wav file and i storage it like this

```
            File file =new File(outputfile);

    outputfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyImages/audio1.wav";
```

When i am opening my AudioPlayer i have this file with my  music what is really bad for me.

I want to hide this file to not be visible for me in AudioPlayer.

I tried to save this file using SharedPreferences but i cant save bytearrays. Ofc i can try:

```
                  String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(audioBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and then:

```
                    byte[] b = Base64.decode(audiodata1, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But then i dont rly know to play sound from this file just using bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the file hidden just put the dot as prefix of your file name `.audio1.wav`:

```
outputfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyImages/.audio1.wav";
```